# How can I run Azure's Get-AzureServiceAntimalwareConfig cmdlet equivalent in the new Azure Cloud Power Shell 'Az'

Tags: azure, module, azure-powershell, powershell-cmdlet, azure-cloud-shell

In Azure Power Shell within the Azure cmdlet module there is a cmdlet called "Get-AzureServiceAntimalwareConfig". I want to run the equivalent cmdlet but from the new PowerShell Az cmdlet module. How can I find the equivalent cmdlet for 'Az'? Do I need to install a cmdlet module that isn't already installed by default? I'm using Azure Cloud Shell.

Comment: this isnt probably supported, as this is not ARM cmdlet

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no equivalent command of `Get-AzureServiceAntimalwareConfig` in `Az` powershell module.

The command is used to get the antimalware configuration and monitoring configuration details associated with the Microsoft Antimalware extension for a **cloud service**. Cloud service is a classic(**ASM**) service, but the `Az` powershell module is for **ARM**.

Comment: So if my web app is a non-classic azure web app service not running on a VM, how do I turn on the anti malware? Can I do this through Azure Power Shell (or cloud shell) using AzureRM? I'm trying to increase security against the issue noted in this recent article.

Comment: @StackMan If you use the web app, no need to do that, all Azure Web Apps run in a secure environment called a `sandbox`. Each app runs inside its own sandbox, isolating its execution from other instances on the same machine as well as providing an additional degree of security and privacy which would otherwise not be available. For more details, see this [link](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

Comment: Basically you can have malicious content travel through azure services and stored on azure storage that may do no harm until someone else gets the file on their non azure system. It's like Azure is a carrier of infectious files/content. Microsoft docs show the malware scan feature to be off by default. I'm just trying to turn it on. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-antimalware https://www.techrepublic.com/google-amp/article/capitalinstall-malware-targets-healthcare-sector-delivers-payload-via-microsoft-azure/  I tested with EICAR anti-malware test file.

Comment: @StackMan Azure App service is not the same with cloud service, it 24-hour threat management protects the infrastructure and platform against malware, distributed denial-of-service (DDoS), man-in-the-middle (MITM), and other threats, see this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-security). Besides, actually I have answered the specific question `How can I run Azure's Get-AzureServiceAntimalwareConfig cmdlet equivalent in the new Azure Cloud Power Shell 'Az'`, if you have other issues, you can accept the reply and ask for them in another post, thanks.

Comment: I want to know how to scan azure storage (non-VM) using the free antimalware features in Azure. The docs show it WAS possible using AzureRM cmdlets. That would be the answer. I just can't get it to work :(

Comment: I will wait for a better answer.

Comment: @StackMan If you really want to solve your problem, I recommend you to ask the question `how to scan azure storage (non-VM) using the free antimalware features in Azure with AzureRM cmdlets` in another post. For the policy of StackOverFlow, you need to avoid asking several questions in the same post. If you are willing to go your own way, please feel free to do so.;-)

Comment: This quote from MS docs leads me to think you are wrong that there is "no equivalent command". "Az also offers feature parity and an easy migration path from AzureRM." just saying...

Comment: @StackMan `Get-AzureServiceAntimalwareConfig` belongs to `ASM` , not `AzureRM`, I think you can learn something about `Az`, `AzureRM`, `ASM` first.